# Fixed first column horizontal scrolling table link not clickable

Tags: jquery, css

I'm doing a fixed first column horizontal scrolling table, but for some reason if I have a hyperlink in the first column, it isn't clickable once you've scrolled to the right. I think this is because the fixed column is not clickable for some reason, and the only reason why it is clickable to begin with is because of the duplicate table link underneath. Does anyone know of a way to make the link clickable even when the underlaying table is scrolled to the right?

```js
// requires jquery library
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".main-table").clone(true).appendTo('#table-scroll').addClass('clone');   
 });
```

```css
.table-scroll {
 position:relative;
 max-width:600px;
 margin:auto;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
.table-wrap {
 width:100%;
 overflow:auto;
}
.table-scroll table {
 width:100%;
 margin:auto;
 border-collapse:separate;
 border-spacing:0;
}
.table-scroll th, .table-scroll td {
 padding:5px 10px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 background:#fff;
 white-space:nowrap;
 vertical-align:top;
}
.table-scroll thead, .table-scroll tfoot {
 background:#f9f9f9;
}
.clone {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 pointer-events:none;
}
.clone th, .clone td {
 visibility:hidden
}
.clone td, .clone th {
 border-color:transparent
}
.clone tbody th {
 visibility:visible;
 color:red;
}
.clone .fixed-side {
 border:1px solid #000;
 background:#eee;
 visibility:visible;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}
.clone thead, .clone tfoot{background:transparent;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en' class=''>
<head><script src='//static.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/console_runner-ce3034e6bde3912cc25f83cccb7caa2b0f976196f2f2d52303a462c826d54a73.js'></script><script src='//static.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/css_live_reload_init-890dc39bb89183d4642d58b1ae5376a0193342f9aed88ea04330dc14c8d52f55.js'></script><meta charset='UTF-8'><meta name="robots" content="noindex"><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="//static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/favicon-8ea04875e70c4b0bb41da869e81236e54394d63638a1ef12fa558a4a835f1164.ico" /><link rel="mask-icon" type="" href="//static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/logo-pin-f2d2b6d2c61838f7e76325261b7195c27224080bc099486ddd6dccb469b8e8e6.svg" color="#111" /><link rel="canonical" href="https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/gWoVzN" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style class="cp-pen-styles">.table-scroll {
 position:relative;
 max-width:600px;
 margin:auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
.table-wrap {
 width:100%;
 overflow:auto;
}
.table-scroll table {
 width:100%;
 margin:auto;
 border-collapse:separate;
 border-spacing:0;
}
.table-scroll th, .table-scroll td {
 padding:5px 10px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 background:#fff;
 white-space:nowrap;
 vertical-align:top;
}
.table-scroll thead, .table-scroll tfoot {
 background:#f9f9f9;
}
.clone {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 pointer-events:none;
}
.clone th, .clone td {
 visibility:hidden
}
.clone td, .clone th {
 border-color:transparent
}
.clone tbody th {
 visibility:visible;
 color:red;
}
.clone .fixed-side {
 border:1px solid #000;
 background:#eee;
 visibility:visible;
}
.clone thead, .clone tfoot{background:transparent;}</style></head><body>
<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <table class="main-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 3</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 4</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 5</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 6</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 7</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 8</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side"><a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Left Column</a></th>
          <td>Cell content<br>
            test</td>
          <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">&nbsp;</th>
          <td>Footer 2</td>
          <td>Footer 3</td>
          <td>Footer 4</td>
          <td>Footer 5</td>
          <td>Footer 6</td>
          <td>Footer 7</td>
          <td>Footer 8</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<script src='//static.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-b2a7b3fe212eaa732349046d8416e00a9dec26eb7fd347590fbced3ab38af52e.js'></script><script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script >// requires jquery library
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".main-table").clone(true).appendTo('#table-scroll').addClass('clone');   
 });

//# sourceURL=pen.js
</script>
</body></html>
```

Original code reference: https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/gWoVzN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have disabled **pointer events** on `.clone` class. I am not sure if it is necessary for other operations of your purpose but it prevents clicks as a pointer event. I have modified styles for `.clone` below:

```js
// requires jquery library
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".main-table").clone(true).appendTo('#table-scroll').addClass('clone');   
 });
```

```css
.table-scroll {
 position:relative;
 max-width:600px;
 margin:auto;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
.table-wrap {
 width:100%;
 overflow:auto;
}
.table-scroll table {
 width:100%;
 margin:auto;
 border-collapse:separate;
 border-spacing:0;
}
.table-scroll th, .table-scroll td {
 padding:5px 10px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 background:#fff;
 white-space:nowrap;
 vertical-align:top;
}
.table-scroll thead, .table-scroll tfoot {
 background:#f9f9f9;
}
.clone {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
.clone th, .clone td {
 visibility:hidden
}
.clone td, .clone th {
 border-color:transparent
}
.clone tbody th {
 visibility:visible;
 color:red;
}
.clone .fixed-side {
 border:1px solid #000;
 background:#eee;
 visibility:visible;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}
.clone thead, .clone tfoot{background:transparent;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <table class="main-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 3</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 4</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 5</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 6</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 7</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 8</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side"><a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Left Column</a></th>
          <td>Cell content<br>
            test</td>
          <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">&nbsp;</th>
          <td>Footer 2</td>
          <td>Footer 3</td>
          <td>Footer 4</td>
          <td>Footer 5</td>
          <td>Footer 6</td>
          <td>Footer 7</td>
          <td>Footer 8</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic! :) It actually was important to have the pointer-events turned off in order for the rest of the table to be scrollable, so I added pointer-events: auto to the clone fixed side class. Thank you so much!